# Partial View Checkbox's not working inside Normal View

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have a partial view that pops up on button click. The partial view displays fine but when i try to click the form check boxes they do not display checked. I am not sure what's going on but it seems like the check box event never gets fired or something along those lines. I have tried using loading the partial view using the jquery load function but I cannot seem to get it to load. So instead I am using the AJAX call and inserting the data into a div on the normal view.

Here is my partial view:

```
@model EmployeeMaster.Models.EmployeeAsset

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div  class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">

        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Item</th>
                    <th>Yes/No</th>
                    <th>Item</th>
                    <th>Yes/No</th>
                    <th>Item</th>
                    <th>Yes/No</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.Label("Cellular Telephone : ")
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.CellPhone)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.Label("Mileage Log : ")
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.MileageLog)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.Label("Travel Expense Reports : ")
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.TravelExpenseReports)
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.Label("Computer : ")
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Computer)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.Label("Pager : ")
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Pager)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.Label("Uniforms : ")
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Uniforms)
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.Label("Customer Database : ")
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.CustomerDatabase)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.Label("PhoneCard : ")
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.PhoneCard)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.Label("Vehicle : ")
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Vehicle)
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.Label("Gas Card : ")
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.GasCard)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.Label("Security Card : ")
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.SecurityCard)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.Label("Co Credit Card : ")
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.CoCreditCard)
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.Label("Keys : ")
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Keys)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.Label("Tools : ")
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Tools)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.Label("Other PPG Property : ")
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.OtherPPGProperty)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
}
```

This is my jquery I use on my normal view to call the partial view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#assets-button").on("click", function () {

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: '@Url.Action("EmployeeAssets", "Employee", new { empNo = Model.EmployeeNumber })',
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#assets-container').html(data);
                    }
                });
                $('#assets-container').bPopup(
                {
                    modal: true,
                    appendTo: '#employee-edit-form'
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Here is my div I use to store the partial view:

```
<div id="assets-container" style="display: none;position:absolute;background-color: white; padding: 10px;"></div>
```

Here is a screen shot:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is inside the partial view. The div surrounding the table has a class of "class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio"" and that is is conflicting with the checkbox buttons. Remove the div class and it works.